# Getting horizontal scrollbar in Material UI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Mui datagrid component and getting horizontal scrollbar.

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'fileName', headerName: 'File Name', flex: 2, headerClassName: 'table-header' },
    { field: 'status', headerName: 'Status', renderCell: RenderBadge, flex: 1, headerClassName: 'table-header' },
    { field: 'reason', headerName: 'Reason', flex: 1, headerClassName: 'table-header' }
  ];

const rows = [{
    "fileName": "abc.txt", "status": "Completed", "reason": "XYZ",
}];

<DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={() => generateRandom()}
        initialState={{
          pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 25 } }
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[25, 50, 75, 100]}
      />
```

Actual output

[image]

Expected

[image]

how to remove the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

From here https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/8772#issuecomment-1535474430

It is possible to hide it using CSS.

in a global way that is not recommended like this:

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
```

Or in a direct way like this:

```
.MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: initial;
}
```